# How to make auto change "Show Entries" value with Tampermonkey or Stylebot?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, stylebot

https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html

From this page, it's Show "10" Entries. How can we change to "50" every time we open this web by using Tampermonkey or Stylebot in Chrome Browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. get select element:
   `const select = document.querySelector('[name=example_length]');`
2. change select value:
   `select.value = 50;`
3. trigger change event:
   `select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`

Comment: This will only work sometimes on that page. The page is AJAX-driven and the Tampermonkey script can fire before the `<select>` is ready.

Comment: That page's data is locally.

Comment: The page's *data* may be static; but the select is added via javascript, and thus this code will not always work.

Comment: You are right, that's my mistake, thank you. And your answer is great, `waitForKeyElements` is a great way to find elements with callback function.